# CakePHP 2.4 Forgotten Password

Tags: cakephp, forgot-password

I have just started using CakePHP and love using it! I have created a login system and registration system, however am really struggling with the "forgotten password" section.

I want to use a tokenhash and expiry date in the Users DB so that it cant be abused, users would need to enter username and email to get an activation link emailed to them with a newly generated tokenhash

There are quite a few tutorials out there but I find most of them work for the first part e.g. emailing the activation link/ resetting token and timer but all seem to fail on the change of the password.

Please help me, either with a working tutorial from the net or a solution that applies the above required things.

Thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: http://github.com/cakedc/users use it or look at the code if you want to do it by yourself. The plugin covers what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I am writing the code that I wrote for one of my project, this might help you out.

1- I created a new table which contains the unique token for every user.

Table Name:- user_password_resets

Columns : userclient_id, token

2- A email template name as:- change_password.html inside /webroot/template/change_password.html

```
public function login_send() {
       $this->isLoggedIn(); //Check if the user is logged in
      if($this->request->is('post')) { #if the form is submitted
        $login = $this->data['User']['login'];
        $conditions = array('User.login'=>$login);
        if($this->User->hasAny($conditions)) {
            $users = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
            #Generate the token
            $token = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
            #Save token and other details in user_password_reset_links table
            $users = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('User.login'=>$login)));
            $my_name = $users['User']['first_name'];
            $reset_links = array();
            $reset_links['UserPasswordReset']['userclient_id'] = $users['User']['client_id'];
            $reset_links['UserPasswordReset']['token'] = $token;

            $conditions = array('UserPasswordReset.userclient_id'=>$users['User']['client_id']);
            if($this->UserPasswordReset->hasAny($conditions)) {
                 $user_id = $users['User']['client_id'];
                $this->UserPasswordReset->updateAll(array('UserPasswordReset.token'=>"'$token'"), array("UserPasswordReset.userclient_id"=>"$user_id"));    
            } else {
                $this->UserPasswordReset->create();
               $this->UserPasswordReset->save($reset_links);
            }
            $password_reset_link = BASE_URL."users/reset_password/$token";

            #Send Welcome Email
            $mailContent = file_get_contents(BASE_URL . "templates/change_password.html");
            $rootlink = BASE_URL;
            $arrMail = array(
                "{NICK}" => ucfirst($my_name),
                "{rootlink}" => BASE_URL,
                "{SITE_TITLE}" => SITE_TITLE,
                "{PASSWORD_RESET_LINK}"=>$password_reset_link
                );

             $mails = explode(',', $users['User']['email']);    
            $msg = @str_replace(array_keys($arrMail), array_values($arrMail), $mailContent);
            $data = array();
            $data['to'] = @$mails[0];
            $data['body'] = $msg;
            $data['subject'] = SITE_TITLE.'- Reset Password.';
            $this->send_mail($data);

            $this->Session->setFlash('A password reset link has been sent to the email address.', 'default', array('class'=>'successMsg'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'));
            exit;
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The Username entered is not registered with Captain Marketing.', 'default', array('class'=>'errorMsg'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login_send'));
            exit;
        }
    }
    $this->set('title_for_layout', '-Send password reset link');
  }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks Dinesh, I like this script, how does your reset_password view look / function work? that is the main bit I am struggling with, I like how you have done this though

Comment: I am generating a unique token, saving it along with the user_id in a new table, sending an reset password token email to the client. The client when clicks on the reset password token and users comes to my site i am checking the date of token creation if it is not expired, the new password is saved otherwise the user is notified that the token is expired. try again

Comment: ah ok yes that makes sense sorry I didn't read the code correctly :) I will test that as soon as I can. thanks